# Cannot create CV location issue

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

When I try to create CV I cannot as it says 'This location is not specific enough. You must provide at least the city you are currently in.'

I live in 'Male' the main City of Maldives. It is displayed correctly as Male, Maldives but Stack Overflow is not recognizing my city so I get an error as not specific enough. What can be done?

Comment: When I enter "Male, Maldives" in the CV field, it doesn't show up in the lookup drop-down (which is strange/annoying) but I can save the info. At which poin t are you getting the error message?

Answer (score 2):

We've had this problem a couple of times and it's kind of difficult to fix for the general case... Basically we use Google's geo-coder under the hood and it identifies "Male, Maldives" as a geocoded [location](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Male,%20Maldives) of type `administrative_area_level_1` and `political`.

Our geocoding implementation takes that and infers it to be a state or region. Sadly we can't change that globally because, well, there are a lot of things that are of type `administrative_area_level_1` or `political` that don't map to cities at all.

I've implemented a workaround that treats the Maldives as a special-case to the general implementation and pushed it to prod. That should get you going!

Comment: So does that mean I can try to check if it works now or should I wait until you confirm that it will work?

Comment: It should be worked by as of now...